# Rounding off decimals at a particular decimal number java

Tags: java

How to get correct time when subtracting decimal numbers. I wanted to subtract numbers as if it were tiime. But time only goes to 60 minutes whereas numbers to 100. How could I put some sort of restriction on the decimal places to make it like time.

Comment: But seriously now, you can use modulo `%`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  The elapsed time is in milliseconds, as that is what you have when you subtract a start System.currentTimeMillis() from a finish System.currentTimeMillis().

```
public String formatElapsedTime(long elapsedTime) {
    int centiseconds = (int) (((elapsedTime % 1000L) + 5L) / 10L);
    centiseconds %= 10;
    int seconds = (int) (elapsedTime / 1000L);
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes -= hours * 60;

    if (hours > 0) {
        return String.format("%2d:%02d:%02d.%02d", hours, minutes, seconds,
                centiseconds);
    } else if (minutes > 0) {
        return String.format("%2d:%02d.%02d", minutes, seconds,
                centiseconds);
    } else {
        return String.format("%2d.%02d", seconds, centiseconds);
    }
}
```

You probably don’t need to display centiseconds when you’re measuring elapsed time in hours.

Because my format strings start with “%2d”, seconds, minutes, and hours less than 10 have a space as the first character of the string. I find this keeps the display from jumping so much. If you don’t want the leading space, change the format String to “%1d”.

You can calculate days as well, for really long elapsed times. You would probably want a format like “3 days, 6 hours, 25 minutes, and 13 seconds”. Or not.

Comment: Sorry to comment here, but I have to ask and this is the only way to ping you: Why did you protect http://stackoverflow.com/q/24062974/1849664?

Comment: @Undo: Because someone with a reputation of 1 wrote a comment as an answer.  I flagged the comment and protected the question so a person with a reputation of 1 could not comment with an answer again.

Comment: Understand, thank you. A few years ago [guidance was published](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/) that says we should only protect these where they have a "long history of unproductive answers," which is why I ask.

Comment: @Undo.  Ok, thanks for the information.  I don't go looking for questions to protect, but I usually protect questions where someone writes a comment as an answer.

Comment: No problem. It might be worth making a slight change and only protecting ones with multiple comment-answers posted within a short timeframe. No harm done either way :)